# Bootstrap Studio-Freemarker Issue

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, freemarker

This is chiefly a production architecture question.

First a few facts to frame the question:

1) I dislike coding in raw HTML

2) I despise JavaScript (but I like the end products of it)

3) I need a dynamically adjusting page based on user (which Freemarker is perfect for)

The problem is that [Boostrap Studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io/) outputs very specific HTML, which I would then have to modify by hand in order to make it Freemarker compatible.  So, every time I change anything on the fundamental page design, I would have to redo all of the Freemarker edits to the page, since Boostrap Studio does not allow edits to the raw HTML.

So the question:

How can I combine the benefits of Boostrap Studio, which generates the HTML for me, with the flexibility of Freemarker?

Corollary question:
Is there a better HTML WYSIWYG editor than Bootstrap Studio that plays nicely with Freemarker?

I have a few rough ideas for solutions, but I don't like any of them.

1) I can ditch Freemarker, and just work in raw JavaScript in Bootstrap Studio.

2) I can ditch Bootstrap Studio and work in raw HTML and have Freemarker work the dynamic parts of the page.

3) I can use some kind of rudimentary JavaScript to translate Freemarker stuff to the Bootstrap Studio output.

But I figured I will throw this out there.  SO has a lot of clever people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Bootstrap Studio has a [Custom Code](https://bootstrapstudio.io/forums/topic/writing-html-in-bootstrap-studio/) block that allows you to write custom HTML including Freemarker tags and the Bootstrap Studio application ignores this code when previewing.

This seems to fill the gap between the two nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Export your code from Bootstrap Studio and open it on your integrated development environment (IDE). Edit the html there and run it locally to make sure it fits your needs.